# Typedef redefinition with different types using C library in Xcode iOS Framework

Tags: c, objective-c, swift, xcode

I'm using a C library in Obj-C and Swift mixed iOS project.

In this library, they use `typedef int BOOL` to define a `BOOL` type in the public header. However, BOOL is a keyword in the obj-c, therefore, it will report compile error.

Is there anyway to solve this problem without modifying any source code?

Comment: This is a heavily wild suggestion, having never used Objective C or Swift. Could you `#define BOOL ALTERNATE_BOOL` before the header is included, then `#undef BOOL` after the include?

Comment: hey, that does work! Thanks for your help.